# DynamoDB returning null nextToken when there are still results in database

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

I have a GraphQL API (AppSync) backed by a DynamoDB table keyed a specific id with timestamp as the range key. I want to retrieve all possible history for that id so I wrote a query in my GraphQL schema that would allow me to do so. Here's the request vtl:

```
{
    "version": "2017-02-28",
    "operation": "Query",
    "query": {
        "expression": "id = :id",
        "expressionValues": {
            ":id": {
                "S": "$context.args.id"
            }
        }
    },
    "nextToken": $util.toJson($util.defaultIfNullOrEmpty($context.args.nextToken, null))
}
```

There could be thousands of items in the ddb table for an id so I wrote a Lambda function to query for all of them and return the result in a list as such (I know the code can be simplified):

```
exports.handler = async function (event, context, callback) {
    const graphqlClient = new appsync.AWSAppSyncClient({
        url: process.env.APPSYNC_ENDPOINT,
        region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
        auth: {
            type: 'AWS_IAM',
            credentials: {
                accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
                sessionToken: process.env.AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
            }
        },
        disableOffline: true
    });

    const query = gql`query GetAllItemsById(
        $id: String!
        $nextToken: String
    ) {
        getAllItemsById(
            id: $id
            nextToken: $nextToken
        ) {
            exampleField {
                subField1
                subField2
                subField3
            }
            nextToken
        }
    }
    `;

    const initialResult = await graphqlClient.query({
        query,
        variables: {
            id: event.id
        }
    });

    var finalResult = initialResult.data.getAllItemsById.exampleField;
    var nextToken = initialResult.data.getAllItemsById.nextToken;

    while (nextToken !== null) {
        const result = await graphqlClient.query({
            query,
            variables: {
                id: event.id,
                nextToken: nextToken
            }
        });

        finalResult = finalResult.concat(result.data.getAllItemsById.exampleField);
        nextToken = result.data.getAllItemsById.nextToken;
    }

    console.log("Total Results: " + finalResult.length);

    return callback(null, finalResult);
};
```

For some reason, not all items are being returned. `nextToken` is null before all results are returned. I know DDB has a 1MB limit for query which is why I'm paginating using `nextToken` but why is it still not returning all the items in the table? Also, if there's a better way to implement this, I'm open to it.

Comment: maybe you can enable CW logs and check what was the value of the $ctx.result.nextToken